# jQuery Mobile + Bootstrap - Collapsible navbar menu not toggling after loading another page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, menu, toggle, navbar

I have a JQM + Bootstrap implementation with a collapsible navbar menu that refuses to toggle after loading another page in the app. I'm assuming that the ajax page loads via JQM are interfering with Bootstrap's collapse menu toggle function.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home - Websites 2 Go</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- JSSOR slideshow -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jssor/jssor.css">

    <script src="lib/jssor/jssor.js"></script>

    <!-- All Cart Items -->
    <script src="js/items.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cart.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="cart.html">Cart (0 items)</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Websites 2 Go</a>
        </div>


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->


    <!-- Slideshow -->
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">jssor_1_slider_init();</script>



    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">Build & Buy a Website</h3>
        <div class="ui-body">
            ...
            <br><br>
            <a href="getstarted.html" class="btn btn-default">Get Started</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Copyright &copy; 2016</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<script>
$(document).on('pageshow', function() {
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse();
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I have tried:

```
<script>
$(document).on('pageshow', function() {
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse();
  });
});
</script>


<script>
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse();
  });
});
</script>


<script>
$(document).on('pageload', function() {
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Homen jQuery Mobile handles the page transitions via Ajax. Clicking on a link loads the page in the `#page` container.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to move the navbar above and outside the `data-role="page"` container.